# Does gcc wrap option takes effects on function printf ？

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I wrote a wrap function to replace the `printf` of `stdio.h`. I found that the `wrap` option worked on functions in `stdlib.h`, like `malloc` or `exit`. But it did not work on `printf` or `fprintf`.

Does the option `wrap` takes effects on functions in `stdio.h` ? And how can I wrap an arbitrary function ? I cannot get useful guide from the [ld document](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html).

Here is the code :

```
//gcc wrap.c -g -Wl,--wrap,fprintf
int __real_fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);

int main(){
    fprintf(stderr, "MAIN!\n"); 
    return 0;
}

int __wrap_fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...){
    __real_fprintf(stderr, "WRAP!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to wrap variadic functions, you should initialize the arg list and then pass it to, e.g, v*printf

Comment: "it did not work" What output did you expect? What output did you get?

Comment: Confirmed doesn't work for fprintf. It works for malloc.

Comment: @n.m. I want to get the output "WRAP!". But it wrote "MAIN!". The result showed the wrap did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want this to work properly for `fprintf`, you need to also add the flag `-fno-builtin-fprintf` to the command line.  Othwise, gcc will optimize the call to `fprintf` to instead call `fwrite`, and the linker will not see a call to `fprintf` to wrap.

In general, to properly wrap *any* function, you may need the corresponding `-fno-builtin-` option as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. In addition, the code works correctly on `clang`.

Answer (score 3):

`fprintf` without arguments (other than the format string) is optimized to `fwrite`. Change your call of `fprintf` to `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "MAIN!");` and the wrapping will take effect.

```
int __real_fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);

int main(){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "MAIN!"); 
    return 0;
}

int __wrap_fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...){
    __real_fprintf(stderr, "WRAP!\n");
    return 0;
}
```