# snprintf() optimized out despite -fno-builtin on GCC 11

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, mocking, printf

I'm trying to wrap `snprintf()` in order to mock it for a unit test (via cmocka).

```
int
__wrap_snprintf(char *restrict str, size_t size, const char *restrict format,
                ...)
{
    int rc;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);

    if (mocked) {  // global var
        check_expected_ptr(str);
        check_expected(size);
        check_expected_ptr(format);
        errno = mock_type(int);

        rc = (errno == 0) ? vsnprintf(str, size, format, ap) : -1;
    } else {
        rc = vsnprintf(str, size, format, ap);
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return rc;
}
```

I'm working with a testbed that includes many versions of Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Debian, FreeBSD, OpenSUSE, and Ubuntu. This issue happens only on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS (the two versions in the testbed) and Fedora 36 Power 9. It works fine on every other distro tested.

I've verified that the `__wrap_snprintf()` symbol is available in my unit test code and shares the same address as `snprinf()`. When I call it directly instead of as `snprintf()`, it works as expected. If I call `snprintf()`, `__wrap_snprintf()` does not get called as expected.

I've tried turning off optimization with `__attribute__((optimize("-O0")))`. I've tried removing the `restrict` keyword from my `__wrap_snprintf()` signature. These didn't help. I thought it was a linker issue until I tested with `gcc -O0` and the issue disappeared. I've edited the post to reflect the fact that this is a compiler mis-optimization.

I found this, but the solution doesn't help; I'm already passing arguments after the format string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189436/7660197. Example call:

```
snprintf(buf, NAME_MAX, "%s%s", "hello", "world");
```

Flags:

```
gcc -fno-builtin -fno-inline -g -O2 -pthread -pthread -pthread -pthread -pthread -pthread -ggdb -fgnu89-inline -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wfloat-equal -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wno-long-long -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Werror -Wl,--wrap=calloc -Wl,--wrap=endgrent -Wl,--wrap=fopen -Wl,--wrap=getenv -Wl,--wrap=getpid -Wl,--wrap=getgrent -Wl,--wrap=getpwnam_r -Wl,--wrap=readlink -Wl,--wrap=setenv -Wl,--wrap=setgrent -Wl,--wrap=snprintf -Wl,--wrap=strdup -Wl,--wrap=uname -Wl,--wrap=unsetenv
```

Any ideas of what could be causing the different behavior in Ubuntu 22.04/20.04 and Fedora 36 Power 9 LE?

And any suggestions of the best way to prevent `snprintf()` from being optimized out while keeping optimizations elsewhere? Portable answers are preferred for future-proofing purposes. I need to support gcc and clang, although the misbehavior is occurring only on three of the gcc-using distros right now.

---

Edit:

The issue is that on the Ubuntu systems (and possibly the F36 Power 9 system -- I don't have direct access), the `-fno-builtin` compiler flag is **not** preventing `__builtin___snprintf_chk()` from being used in place of `snprintf()`. Is this a known issue, and/or does anyone know how to avoid it?

Problematic Ubuntu 22.04 system:

```
# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

# strings lib/common/tests/options/.libs/pcmk__env_option_test | grep snprintf
pcmk__mock_snprintf
__snprintf_chk
__wrap_snprintf
snprintf_error_get
pcmk__mock_snprintf
__builtin___snprintf_chk
snprintf_error_get
snprintf_error_get
pcmk__mock_snprintf
__snprintf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4
```

A working F36 x86_64 system:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1)

$ strings lib/common/tests/options/.libs/pcmk__env_option_test | grep snprintf
__wrap_snprintf
pcmk__mock_snprintf
__wrap_snprintf
snprintf_error_get
pcmk__mock_snprintf
snprintf_error_get
snprintf_error_get
pcmk__mock_snprintf
__wrap_snprintf
```

Comment: Stab in the dark, but try `#undef _FORTIFY_SOURCE` at the top of your source file, before any `#include`s

Comment: Thanks but didn't help. It's not defined.

Comment: @zwol You were right. I missed the leading underscore when I tried it the first time. After setting `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` in my `CFLAGS` (conditioned upon unit testing), it's working. Ubuntu `gcc` man page under `-O2`: "           NOTE: In Ubuntu 8.10 and later versions, -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 is set by default, and is activated when -O is set to 2 or higher.  This enables additional compile-time and run-time checks for
           several libc functions.  To disable, specify either -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE or -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0."

Comment: If you want to post an answer, I'll mark it accepted. Otherwise I'll post one and cite the Ubuntu man page.

Comment: As a depressing point of clarification, now that I've triggered a new run in the testbed... the Ubuntu problem is fixed, but it's still failing just on the Fedora 36 Power 9 LE machine. No idea why yet and don't have easy access to a Power 9 reproducer. Maybe I can sort that out in the business week.

Comment: OT note: Why are you running such unit tests on _all_ systems? You test your _sources_, not the compilers, linkers, libraries, do you? Background: I commonly encounter such misunderstanding of the purpose of tests. But your case can be different, I'm just curious.