# Wrapping a function that glibc redefines or aliases

Tags: c, gcc, mocking, linker, ld

I'm trying to wrap `snprintf()` in order to mock it for unit testing. My approach has been to follow the pattern of other mocked functions in the same project -- namely, to use `-Wl,--wrap=snprintf` in `LDFLAGS`.

```
int
__wrap_snprintf(char *restrict str, size_t size, const char *restrict format,
                ...)
{
    int rc;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);

    if (mocked) {  // global var
        check_expected_ptr(str);
        check_expected(size);
        check_expected_ptr(format);
        errno = mock_type(int);

        rc = (errno == 0) ? vsnprintf(str, size, format, ap) : -1;
    } else {
        rc = vsnprintf(str, size, format, ap);
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return rc;
}
```

On all the other test systems besides Fedora 36 ppc64le, this has worked fine. However, Fedora 36 ppc64le has added support for 128-bit long double values: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/PPC64LE_Float128_Transition.

As part of the implementation, glibc maps `snprintf()` to `___ieee128_snprintf()`. As a result, my wrapper doesn't get called when the code calls `snprintf()`. Minimal demonstration without the wrapper linked in:

```
# cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
void func(const char *s)
{
    char buf[16];
    snprintf(buf, 16, "%s", s);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
int main(void)
{
    func("hello world");
}

# gcc -g -O0 -fno-builtin -fno-inline test.c -o test

# gdb ./test
...
Breakpoint 1, func (s=s@entry=0x10020020 "hello world") at test.c:5
5       snprintf(buf, 16, "%s", s);
(gdb) s
0x00007ffff7d54a98 in ___ieee128_snprintf (s=0x7fffffffeac0 "\360\352\377\377\377\177", maxlen=16, format=0x10020010 "%s") at ../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-128ibm-compat/ieee128-snprintf.c:24
```

Is there a way to handle this with `--wrap` as I've been doing for other mocked functions, or is this approach hopeless?

P.S. In [snprintf() optimized out despite -fno-builtin on GCC 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73438635/7660197) we addressed a related issue on Ubuntu, where an implicit `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` was converting `snprintf()` to `__builtin___snprintf_chk()`. The solution was to explicitly undefine `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: sooo `--wrap=___ieee128_snprintf` ? Have you considered this: create a file named `stdio.h`, add it to include path, in that file do `#define snprintf __my_snprintf` followed by `#include_next <stdio.h>` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! That will probably work, just feels hacky. On the other hand, maybe any solution will be. Another thing that seems to work is adding `-Dsnprintf=__wrap_snprintf` to `CFLAGS`. That also feels pretty hacky and I'd be nervous about undefined behavior if I used that approach. I'd basically be doing half of `--wrap`'s job manually.

Comment: Did you check _when exactly_ `snprintf` is replaced by `___ieee128_snprintf`? Is this done in the compiler or in the linker? If done in the compiler, you could search for the symbol in the header files.

Comment: I think what makes the most sense is along the lines of @KamilCuk's comment. I was too busy trying to follow the pattern of what's been done in this project's unit testing before and missed what seems to be an obvious solution for this case... just don't wrap it via the linker at all. Add `-Dsnprintf=test_snprintf` to `CFLAGS` and call the wrapper function `test_snprintf` instead of `__wrap_snprintf`. I don't need `__real_snprintf` anyway, since I'll be passing the `va_list` to `vsnprintf` if I need the real function.